# json.Net save to file

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a script for saving to file sorted, however I cant code it to save to entry: as below

```
{
    "entry": [
        { "Name": "John" },
        { "Name": "Anna" },
        { "Name": "Peter" }
    ]
}
```

Im using json.Net, code below needs to add to entry: name

```
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results, Formatting.Indented);
 string path = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\JSON\json.Net\results.json";

 if (!File.Exists(path))
 {
     File.WriteAllText(path, json);
 }
 else
 {
     File.AppendAllText(path, json);
 }
```

I haven't been able to find any good json code samples, cheers Paul

Comment: Please provide problem details - do you have some error, or not expected results? What results do you expect?

Comment: You can use `FileStream`, write an extension method, create a wrapper class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed it like so!

```
  UserInfo results = new UserInfo
    {
        Name = Request["name"],

    };

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw);
    jsonWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
    jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("Name");
    jsonWriter.WriteValue(results.Name);
    jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();

    string json = sw.ToString();
    jsonWriter.Close();
    sw.Close();

    string path = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\JSON\json.Net\results.json";

    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.WriteAllText(path, json);
    }
    else
    {
        File.AppendAllText(path, json);
    }

}

// create a class object to hold the JSON value
public class UserInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```